What is the spectroscopic factor in nuclear physics?
In the book by Ring and Schuck, the so-called spectroscopic factor is defined as
$$ S_k = |\langle \Psi_{A+1} |a_k^\dagger | \Psi_A \rangle |^2 .$$
By this definition, the spectroscopic factor is upper bounded by unity.
However, in this paper in Nature, in figure 1 and table 1, we see spectroscopic factor larger than 1.
Can anyone explain the reason behind? Are the definitions different?

They write in the paper that you quote:

All of the measured states in 133Sn have large spectroscopic factors
S$\approx$1, and if these were absolute values they would indicate
little fragmentation of the single-particle strength. Because they
are relative values...

So they use some relative values.
